# Detecting date format and converting them to MM-DD-YYYY using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to convert the date formats and make them uniform throughout the document using Python 3.6.
Here is the sample of the dates in my document:(There can be other formats as the document is large.)

```
9/21/1989
19640430
6/27/1980
5/11/1987
Mar 12 1951
2 aug 2015
```

I have checked the `datetime` lbrary. But could not understand hoow to detect and change the format of the dates automatically. Here is what I have checked till now:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> oldformat = '20140716'
>>> datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%Y%m%d')
>>> newformat = datetimeobject.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
>>> print (newformat)
07-16-2014
```

But I am not getting how I can make the program detect the date patterns automatically and convert them to one single uniform pattern of dates as `mm/dd/yyyy`
Kindly, suggest what I need to do, so as to achieve my goal using Python 3.6.

Comment: How do you intend to interpret dates like `2/4/1994`?  Is that February 4th or the 2nd of April?

Comment: i think the best you can do is check if datetimeobject is instance of date isinstance(datetimeobject, datetime.date)

Comment: Yes certainly. I am trying to make the dates in the `MM/DD/yyyy` format. Yes the what you have mentioned is correct

Comment: @Kevin: Generally if a date has the full year on the end it's given to be month / day / year.

Comment: @l'L'l: In the US, maybe.  In Europe they write it the other way round.

Comment: @l'L'l Yes you are correct.

Comment: @Kevin: That would explain the many missed appointments...

Comment: @Kevin I agree with on that point

Comment: Interesting ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have tried using the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.0) library in my code to detect the date strings in any format. and then used the `datetime` library to convert it into the appropriate format.

Here is the code:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> yourdate = dateutil.parser.parse("May 24 2016")
>>>
>>> print(yourdate)
2016-05-24 00:00:00
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> oldformat = yourdate
>>> datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(str(oldformat),'%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
>>> newformat = datetimeobject.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
>>> print (newformat)
05-24-2016
```

This works.

See the image of the output:
[image: tested image]

Comment: While trying this, I'm getting "strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime" error on `datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @TanviP Had you tried my complete code once...? Where you are getting error is, I guess, not due to my code but your own code issues.

Comment: I do not understand where exactly you people are getting the issue? Please specify. It worked for it. Still working for me. May be you have a different problem definition, hence, try something else.

Comment: Jaffer, would you be so kind and tell us the Python version you are using and the `dateutil.__version__`? This code fails to me because `datetime.strptime` wants a `str` and receives yourdate of type `datetime.datetime`.
This won't fail: `datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(str(oldformat),'%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')`

However, since `dateutil.parser.parse` returns `datetime.datetime`, you get the same result with `yourdate.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')` with fewer lines of code.

Comment: May be the version I did not remember was 2.7. I guess. Currently I am using Python 3.5.0. I received the same error and I will edit the answer so that you will get what you want. Allow me to do so.

Comment: Just for posterity, I was trying to use `dateutil.parser.parse` on exif data from images, and it failed completely. The exif date string was `"2009:03:29 12:30:23"`, and the parser returned `datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 5, 12, 30, 23)`. I posted an issue with the project - https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/1209

Answer (score 9):

There is no universal Python way of doing this, but I'd recommend using regex to identify the type and then converting it correctly:

## Example Python

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

with open("in.txt","r") as fi, open("out.txt","w") as fo:
    for line in fi:
        line = line.strip()
        dateObj = None
        if re.match(r"^\d{8}$", line):
            dateObj = datetime.strptime(line,'%Y%m%d')
        elif re.match(r"^\d{1,2}/", line):
            dateObj = datetime.strptime(line,'%m/%d/%Y')
        elif re.match(r"^[a-z]{3}", line, re.IGNORECASE):
            dateObj = datetime.strptime(line,'%b %d %Y')
        elif re.match(r"^\d{1,2} [a-z]{3}", line, re.IGNORECASE):
            dateObj = datetime.strptime(line,'%d %b %Y')
        fo.write(dateObj.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + "\n")
```

## Example Input

```
9/21/1989
19640430
6/27/1980
5/11/1987
Mar 12 1951
2 aug 2015
```

## Example Output

```
09-21-1989
04-30-1964
06-27-1980
05-11-1987
03-12-1951
08-02-2015
```

Comment: Hey, it is a nice one too. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> (There can be other formats as the document is large.)

Unfortunately, Python does not provide "guess what I mean" functionality (although you might be able to repurpose [GNU `date`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html) for that, as it is [quite flexible](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats)).  You will have to make a list of all of the formats you want to support, and then try each in turn (using `datetime.strptime()` as you've shown) until one of them works.

Python does not try to guess because, in an international context, it is not generally possible to divine what the user wants.  In the US, `2/3/1994` means "February 3rd, 1994," but in Europe the same string means "The 2nd of March, 1994."  Python deliberately abstains from this confusion.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your answer. but I think I found one. Let me check it, if works then I will answer the question.